# Reading from data TcpClient inferior to socket

Tags: c#, .net

I have been under the impression that the TcpClient would simplify socket operations in my network applications.

However, it appears that the TcpClient requires to know how much data is supposed to be read from the underlying socket. It looks like the TcpClient.GetStream(..).Read(..) calls Socket.Receive(..) which reads the specified number of bytes.

The TcpClient exposes a NetworkStream which can be quite annoying to handle. Stuff like termination strings and the unreliable DataAvailable property makes the reading of an unknown TCP "packet" complicated.

Using Socket.ReceiveFrom(..) seems to be much more "packet"-oriented.

I usually use TcpClient to bind and handshake etc., and for reading I use

```
        Socket socket = _tcpClient.Client;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint senderRemote = sender;

        int length = socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref senderRemote);

        string replyString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, length);

        return replyString;
```

Some overhead with the buffer initialization, but it beats reading one byte at a time from the Networkstream, and looking for termination characters or strings.

Isn't it a bit weird that TcpClient does not handle reading data in a better way, i.e. the way Socket does?

Comment: TCP sockets ARE a stream of data, they aren't 'packet based'.  It's possible that one end sends a 'packet' of data that is 32Kb long, but by the time it's gone through 15 different internet servers, that 1 packet is now 15 separate 'packets' that could require you to call receive 15 times.   If you aren't seeing this behaviour, then you haven't done enough real world testing.

Comment: @Neil Well, the question relates to TcpClient not TCP sockets per say.

Comment: TcpClient is just a wrapper around Socket, with a few helpers methods and properties.  If you want to use Socket, then there is nothing stopping you (TcpClient.Socket). Blaming TcpSocket for 'being weird' is, IMO, misunderstanding how TCP actually works.

Comment: @Neil I don't believe I'm blaming anything or anyone or claim that TCP sockets are stream based.

Answer (score 1):

There are protocols that have a fixed size header containing the size of the payload, so maybe it's not *that* weird.

In your case you may be better off using `Socket`s directly, or you could write a wrapper around `NetworkStream` that reads into a buffer and allows you to `Peek()` into it for termination characters.